# Elastic APM Agent ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap - Provider "jar" not found

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-apm

We are facing this error in our Spring Cloud Gateway application deployed on Openshift, but it works well in the local but not in Openshift environment.

Below are the details.

Elastic APM Jar version: 1.30.0, 1.29.0 and 1.28.4

Spring boot version: spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE

OpenShift Master: v3.11.0+ec8630f-265

Kubernetes Master: v1.11.0+d4cacc0

OpenShift Web Console: v3.11.0+ea42280

Java: 11.0.14.1

JVM Args:

ERROR log:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport
2022-03-30 14:19:31,658 [main] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.configuration.StartupInfo - Starting Elastic APM 1.30.0 as my-api-gateway on Java 11.0.14.1 Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1 VM version: 11.0.14.1+1 (Eclipse Adoptium) Linux 3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64
2022-03-30 14:19:31,662 [main] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.configuration.StartupInfo - service_name: my-api-gateway' (source: Environment Variables)
2022-03-30 14:19:31,662 [main] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.configuration.StartupInfo - environment: 'PR' (source: Environment Variables)
2022-03-30 14:19:31,662 [main] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.configuration.StartupInfo - enable_experimental_instrumentations: 'true' (source: Java System Properties)
2022-03-30 14:19:31,662 [main] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.configuration.StartupInfo - server_url: 'https://eapm-instance-nonprod.xxxxx.com:443'  (source: Environment Variables)
2022-03-30 14:19:31,663 [main] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.configuration.StartupInfo - server_urls: 'https://eapm-instance-nonprod.xxxxx:443'  (source: Environment Variables)
2022-03-30 14:19:31,663 [main] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.configuration.StartupInfo - application_packages: 'com.my.api.gateway' (source: Environment Variables)
2022-03-30 14:19:33,463 [main] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap - Provider "jar" not found
java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "jar" not found
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.util.PackageScanner.getClassNames(PackageScanner.java:61) ~[elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap.getClassNamesFromBundledPlugin(IndyBootstrap.java:440) ~[elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap.bootstrap(IndyBootstrap.java:399) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.IndyBootstrapDispatcher.bootstrap(IndyBootstrapDispatcher.java:60) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.bytebuddy.Instrumented.isInstrumented(Instrumented.java:34) [?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.bytebuddy.InstallationListenerImpl.onAfterWarmUp(InstallationListenerImpl.java:65) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$InstallationListener$Compound.onAfterWarmUp(AgentBuilder.java:5221) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$WarmupStrategy$Enabled.apply(AgentBuilder.java:11087) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default.doInstall(AgentBuilder.java:10774) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default.installOn(AgentBuilder.java:10712) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.ElasticApmAgent.initInstrumentation(ElasticApmAgent.java:279) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.ElasticApmAgent.initInstrumentation(ElasticApmAgent.java:164) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.ElasticApmAgent.initialize(ElasticApmAgent.java:150) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.premain.AgentMain.loadAndInitializeAgent(AgentMain.java:160) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:1.30.0]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.premain.AgentMain.init(AgentMain.java:101) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:1.30.0]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.premain.AgentMain.premain(AgentMain.java:50) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:1.30.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [gateway.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [gateway.jar:?]
#logback.classic pattern: %d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.3.10.RELEASE)

2022-03-30 14:19:46,779 [main] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap - Provider "jar" not found
java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "jar" not found
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
2022-03-30 14:19:33,470 [main] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap - Provider "jar" not found
java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "jar" not found
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.util.PackageScanner.getClassNames(PackageScanner.java:61) ~[elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap.getClassNamesFromBundledPlugin(IndyBootstrap.java:440) ~[elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap.bootstrap(IndyBootstrap.java:399) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.IndyBootstrapDispatcher.bootstrap(IndyBootstrapDispatcher.java:60) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.bytebuddy.Instrumented.isInstrumented(Instrumented.java:34) [?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.bytebuddy.InstallationListenerImpl.onAfterWarmUp(InstallationListenerImpl.java:65) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$InstallationListener$Compound.onAfterWarmUp(AgentBuilder.java:5221) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$WarmupStrategy$Enabled.apply(AgentBuilder.java:11087) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default.doInstall(AgentBuilder.java:10774) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default.installOn(AgentBuilder.java:10712) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.ElasticApmAgent.initInstrumentation(ElasticApmAgent.java:279) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.ElasticApmAgent.initInstrumentation(ElasticApmAgent.java:164) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.ElasticApmAgent.initialize(ElasticApmAgent.java:150) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.premain.AgentMain.loadAndInitializeAgent(AgentMain.java:160) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:1.30.0]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.premain.AgentMain.init(AgentMain.java:101) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:1.30.0]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.premain.AgentMain.premain(AgentMain.java:50) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:1.30.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source) [?:?]
2022-03-30 14:19:33,472 [main] WARN  co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.bytebuddy.InstallationListenerImpl - Warmup: instrumented bytecode of co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.bytebuddy.Instrumented does not work as expected
2022-03-30 14:19:35,597 [main] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.report.ReporterConfiguration - Both "server_urls" and "server_url" configuration options are set, therefore the "server_urls" configuration will be ignored.
2022-03-30 14:19:35,662 [elastic-apm-server-healthcheck] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap - Provider "jar" not found
java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "jar" not found
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.util.PackageScanner.getClassNames(PackageScanner.java:61) ~[elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap.getClassNamesFromBundledPlugin(IndyBootstrap.java:440) ~[elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.IndyBootstrap.bootstrap(IndyBootstrap.java:399) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.IndyBootstrapDispatcher.bootstrap(IndyBootstrapDispatcher.java:60) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.util.UrlConnectionUtils.openUrlConnectionThreadSafely(UrlConnectionUtils.java:29) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.report.ApmServerClient.startRequestToUrl(ApmServerClient.java:139) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.report.ApmServerClient.executeForAllUrls(ApmServerClient.java:276) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.report.ApmServerHealthChecker.call(ApmServerHealthChecker.java:65) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.report.ApmServerHealthChecker.call(ApmServerHealthChecker.java:42) [elastic-apm-agent.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
```